# Lazy loading React components doesn't improve performance or reduce bundle size

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, lighthouse, code-splitting

I have the following code to dynamically import based on routes, however it doesn't actually improve performance or decrease the bundle size in anyway? Am I missing something or is it just a case of code splitting not affecting performance that much?

```
const Home = lazy(() => import("./home/index"));
const SignUp = lazy(() => import("./home/sign-up/index"));
const HomeOld = lazy(() => import("./home-old/Home"));
const Demo = lazy(() => import("./home/demo/index"));

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>loading..</h1>}>
        <OfflineWrapper>
          <ScrollToTop />
        </OfflineWrapper>
      </Suspense>
    )
    // ...routes defined
```

- ensured the routes were wrapped in `Suspense`.
- I have checked that the components are lazy loading as the pages error if the `Suspense` is not there.